# Create Edit Control Block (ECB) on View with JSLink

Tags: list-view, sharepoint-server, jslink

I have a question about ECB: In Sharepoint 2013, how to create Edit Control Block (ECB) in view with JSLink.

- I use JSLink to modify the default view, but I can't display the ECB
  context menu with "View item", "New item" ... I don't want use XSLT
  or custom action. Per my employer, I must to use JSLink to do it.
- I update JSLink for View in FeatureReceiver.cs, not using orther
  webpart. My View is OK, but missing ECB.

Here is a picture of my custom view:

[image]
Standard view in SP2013

[image]

This is my JavaScript code:

```
(function () {
var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;
itemCtx.OnPostRender = [];
itemCtx.OnPostRender.push(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // use this method to extend ECB on common lists...
         function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx) {
         // Adding a simple command to the ECB
         CAMOpt(m, 'Go to', 'javascript:STSNavigate("http://www.abc.com");return false;'); 
         // Adding a separator to the ECB
         CAMSep(m);                 
         } 
         // use this method to extend ECB on libraries...
         function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx) {} 

    });
});
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
var id = ctx.CurrentItem["ID"];
var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem["Content"];
var createBy = ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].title;
var modified = ctx.CurrentItem["Modified"];
var att = ctx.CurrentItem["Attachments"];
var attImg = "";
if (att == true) {
    attImg = attImg + "<img src='/../../_layouts/15/images/attach.gif' />&nbsp;";
}
return "<tr><td></td><td vAlign='top' style='width:20px;padding-left:8px;'>" + attImg + "</td><td colspan='2' style='padding-left:40px;'><img style='cursor:pointer' onclick='Expand(" + id + ");' id='imgId" + id + "' src='" + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Images/minus.gif' /><span style='padding-left:5px'><a style='cursor:pointer;font-size:1em' href='" + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Lists/Bulletin%20Board/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + id + "'>" + _announcementTitle + "</a></span><div id='sh" + id + "' style='padding-left:15px;'>" + _announcementDesc + "</div></td><td>" + createBy + "</td><td>" + modified + "</td></tr>";}

function Expand(id) {
var dsStatus = document.getElementById('sh' + id).style.display;
var url = L_Menu_BaseUrl;
if (dsStatus == 'none') {
    jQuery("#imgId" + id).attr('src', url + '/Images/minus.gif');
    $('#sh' + id).show();
}
else {
    jQuery("#imgId" + id).attr('src', url + '/images/plus.gif');
    $('#sh' + id).hide();
}
```

}

What is struct HTML of ECB? I return missing ECB, so how can I resolve that issue?

Comment: Anyone can help me, please! I am so tired with this issues :((

Answer (score 2):

ok, i have fixed this issue.

ECB not show because struct HTML return in ItemOverrideFun not correct.

This is final Javascript code:

```
(function () {
var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 104;

itemCtx.OnPostRender = [];
itemCtx.OnPostRender.push(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        HideHeaderView();
    });
});

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

 })();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {
var itemctxId = ctx.ctxId;

var itemId = ctx.ctxId + "," + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "," + ctx.CurrentItemIdx;

var id = ctx.CurrentItem["ID"];
var _announcementTitle = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
var _announcementDesc = ctx.CurrentItem["Content"];
var createBy = ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].title;
var modified = ctx.CurrentItem["Modified"];
var att = ctx.CurrentItem["Attachments"];
var attImg = "";
if (att == true) {
    attImg = attImg + "<img src='/../../_layouts/15/images/attach.gif' />&nbsp;";
}

var rt = "<tr id='" + itemId + "' iid='" + itemId + "' oncontextmenu='return ShowCallOutOrECBWrapper(this, event, false)' class=' ms-itmHoverEnabled ms-itmhover' setedgeborder='true'><td tabindex='0' class='ms-cellStyleNonEditable ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-imgFirstCell'><div tabindex='-1' class='s4-itm-cbx s4-itm-imgCbx' role='checkbox' title='Test item'><span class='s4-itm-imgCbx-inner'><span class='ms-selectitem-span'><img src='/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23' alt='' class='ms-selectitem-icon'></span></span></div></td>" +
            "<td vAlign='top' style='width:20px;padding-left:8px;'>" + attImg + "</td>" +
            "<td colSpan='2' height='100%' isecb='TRUE' class='ms-cellstyle ms-vb-title ms-positionRelative'>" +
                "<img style='cursor:pointer' onclick='Expand(" + id + ");' id='imgId" + id + "' src='" + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Images/minus.gif'/><span style='padding-left:5px'>" +
                "<div eventtype='' perm='0x7fffffffffffffff' field='Title' id='" + id + "' ctxname='ctx" + itemctxId + "' class='ms-vb  ms-vb-menuPadding itx'>" +
                    "<a target='_self' onclick='EditLink2(this, " + itemctxId + ");return false;' href='" + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Lists/Bulletin%20Board/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + id + "' onfocus='OnLink(this)' class='ms-listlink ms-draggable' dragid='0' draggable='true'>" + _announcementTitle + "</a>" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "<div id='sh" + id + "' style='padding-left:15px;'>" + _announcementDesc + "</div>" +
             "</td>" +
             "<td>" + createBy + "</td>" +
             "<td>" + modified + "</td>" +
             "<td class='ms-list-itemLink-td ms-cellstyle ms-vb-lastCell ms-vb-lastCell'><div onclick='ShowECBMenuForTr(this, event); return false;' class='ms-list-itemLink '><a href='#' onclick='ShowECBMenuForTr(this.parentNode, event); return false; ' title='Open Menu' class='ms-lstItmLinkAnchor ms-ellipsis-a' ms-jsgrid-click-passthrough='true'><img alt='Open Menu' src='/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23' class='ms-ellipsis-icon'></a></div></td>" +
         "</tr>";

    return rt;
 }


 function Expand(id) {

   var dsStatus = document.getElementById('sh' + id).style.display;
   var url = L_Menu_BaseUrl;
   if (dsStatus == 'none') {
    jQuery("#imgId" + id).attr('src', url + '/Images/minus.gif');
    $('#sh' + id).show();
  }
   else {
    jQuery("#imgId" + id).attr('src', url + '/images/plus.gif');
    $('#sh' + id).hide();
   }
 }

 function HideHeaderView() {
   $('div.ms-vh-div').filter('[DisplayName~="Body"],[CTXNum~="3"]').hide();    
}
```