# Sharepoint JSlink ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].title;

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jslink

I am stuck getting the name of the Author/editor.

I am overwriting the templates.item:

```
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = newView.customItem;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
```

In the customItem i am looping over the items and itemfields. This works oke, but not for the Author. The value for Author returns 1, instead of a name I was hoping for:

```
var newView = newView || {};
newView.customItem = function(ctx) {

var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)  {

        var Html = "<tr class='itemRow'><td>";

        var fields = ctx.ListSchema.Field.length;
        for (var i=0;i<fields;i++)  {

            var thisFieldLabel = ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].DisplayName;
            var thisFieldName = ctx.ListSchema.Field[i].RealFieldName;
            var thisFieldNameValue = checkStatusKpi(ctx.CurrentItem[thisFieldName]);

            Html += "<tr class = 'fieldRow'>";
            Html += "<td class = 'fieldLabel'>" + thisFieldLabel + "</td>";
            Html += "<td class = 'fieldValue'>" + thisFieldNameValue + "</td>";
            Html += "</tr>";
        }
        Html += "</td></tr>";
     }
    return Html;
};
```

I did read and try posts without any luck:

1. [JSLink: Userfields (Author, Editor, ...) only provide userId not username](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104828/jslink-userfields-author-editor-only-provide-userid-not-username) and
2. [Create Edit Control Block (ECB) on View with JSLink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97189/create-edit-control-block-ecb-on-view-with-jslink/97229#97229)

Trying to console.log without any luck:

```
console.log("Created by: " + ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].title); // value = undefined
console.log("Created by: " + ctx.CurrentItem["Author"]); // value = 1
```

Can anyone help me out with this, many thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the author/editor field is displayed in the list view. Sometimes you might have to edit the web part and apply your view again after making changes to the view.

Comment: Thank you both. Editing the webpart didnt do it, but rebuilding the JS link did give me the object of the "Author" finally.

Comment: The only code I removed was the looping over the rows. This was a overkill as I was editing "overrideCtx.Templates.Item".

It didnt solve my problem, I think it must have been a caching issue.

At least now I can check (in my case on checkStatusKpi) for an object and get the correct value of it as well:
if (typeof currentValue === 'object') {
  currentValue = currentValue[0].title;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].["title"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use

```
ctx.CurrentItem["Author"][0].title
```